# How to use babel in angular16

Tags: angular, babeljs, angular-cli

In angualr16, we can set browserslist to control the target of output.
when I set as follow
"browserslist": [
"chrome 80"
],
and do the ng build
then build target be set to ES2015

But I want to use new feature of ES2022 e.g. array.at
I find that the output is not be downlevel, javascript is still use array.at which can not be executed in chrome 80
The reason is that
**TypeScript compiler only performs downleveling of syntax (recognizable by special characters like =>, ?, `, # and keywords like class or static) but it does not downlevel the API itself.If you need to polyfill API calls, such as Array.prototype.flat introduced in ES2019, you would require an additional JavaScript compiler like Babel.
**

So did angualr16 alreadz support this scenario, or i need to do some extra setting for Babel , Thanks!

Comment: `npm i @babel/core` [Repository](https://github.com/babel/babel) [Homepage](https://babel.dev/docs/babel-core)

Answer (score 0):

The v16 Angular CLI overwrites the `target` value with `ES2022`.

Under the hood, it uses babel and the browserlist to ensure the browser support you required by transpilling the necessary code.

So if you set your browserlist correctly, there is nothing else to do.

Comment: do you mean, if i run ng build , then the babel will be called implicit ?, _my settting is "browserslist": [ "chrome 80" ], I think it is the correct. I debugger the cli, the target already be reset to ES 2015 according to browserlist setting-  but the it do not work, the output can not execute on Chrome 80, because  at function is not defined.